# How to write a two line function definition? (With domain/codomain on one line, and element/mapsto/element on the other.)

Tags: equations

How can I write this to look as neat as this:

[image]

Edit: What I have tried so far

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
M_f : \pi_1(S \backslash \{y_1, \cdots, y_n\}, y) &\rightarrow& \text{Bij}(f^{-1}(y)) \\
\gamma &\mapsto& M_f(\gamma) = \sigma_\gamma^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

which yields

[image]

This does not align nicely like the upper formula.

(BTW, how to get the better looking `\pi` in the first picture?)

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possibilities (inline or not). Don't use `eqnarray`, which has bad horizontal spacing around the alignment points, and replace it with `align*` or `aligned`. Also, for set difference, use `\(small)setminus`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator\Bij{Bij}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  M_f \colon \pi_1(S \smallsetminus \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}, y) & \longrightarrow \Bij(f^{-1}(y)) \\
  \gamma & \longmapsto M_f(\gamma) = \sigma_\gamma^{-1}
\end{align*}

Or this:\medskip

Let $ S' =S \smallsetminus \{y_1, \dots, y_n\} $. Define
$ \begin{aligned}[t]
M_f \colon \pi_1(S', y) &\longrightarrow \Bij(f^{-1}(y)) \\
\gamma &\longmapsto M_f(\gamma) = \sigma_\gamma^{-1}
\end{aligned} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\smallsetminus` should be deleted from all hard drives in the world.

Comment: @percusse: Why that???

Comment: It is not small and not minus and horribly ugly spaced and so on

Comment: Well, it's spaced as any binary operator and it's smaller that \setminus and it's \*set*minus. And of course, I could use a plain minus sign, as Bourbaki ;o)

Comment: Look at the second picture of OP. That's a proper set minus not this diagonal stick figure. And it is not a binary operator as it is basically a set notation with some flair. But it's still a nitpick anyways.

Comment: I'll be pernickety: it's a binary operator on subsets. And the O.P. asks for such a ‘neat’ looking sign, since there's no restriction on the neatness of the first formula ;o)

Comment: That might be what bourbakians might argue but I would definitely not accept to have the set complement as a binary operator in a definiton. That's simply math snobbery for notation ;)

Answer (score 4):

The example you're trying to reproduce was likely written using [XY-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix?lang=en), which is usually used for typesetting commutative diagrams. I was able to reproduce it with the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R=0cm{
    % the "@R=0cm" minimizes the row height, so you get the two-line effect
    M_f : \pi_1(S \smallsetminus \{y_1, \dotsc, y_n\}, y) \ar[r]
    & \operatorname{Bij}\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)\\
    % \ar@{|->} produces the \mapsto arrow
    \gamma \ar@{|->}[r] & M_f(\gamma) = \sigma_\gamma^{-1}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

It also looks like they use `\smallsetminus` from the `amssymb` package, rather than `\setminus`, but I don't know how they got a different π.

Here's the result I got with that code.
[image]

XY can produce confusing-looking code; for a reference, I would recommend [Wikibooks' guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Xy-pic) or [the XYGuide](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator\Bij{Bij}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep= small,row sep=0ex]
    M_f \colon \pi_1(S \smallsetminus \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}, y) \arrow[r]& \Bij(f^{-1}(y)) \\
   \gamma \arrow[r, mapsto]                                   & M_f(\gamma) = \sigma_{\gamma}^{-1}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `row sep` should be reduced

Comment: @egreg Thanks and I changed. But what would be the correct size is a mystery to me.

Comment: Possibly zero. I have come to the conclusion that such a layout is good at the blackboard, but ugly as hell on paper.

Comment: @egreg: I made it zero. Thanks. I agree that it looks awful.